# Project can't find Enterprise Library Dll's

Tags: reference, enterprise-library-5

My project can't seem to find my enterprise library dll's even though they are in the correct folder?  Why on earth would that occur?  This is the latest enterprise library 5.0.505.0...

Looking at my csproj file it simply includes a refrence for each EnterpriseLibrary file...  Why is it having a hard time finding them...

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Everything seems on the up-and-up.  I will continue to look into this.  Maybe I have the wrong version installed or something similar to that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  It seems as though I had the wrong versions of Enterprise Library on my machine.  And even though I installed the new version on my machine, it didn't look like it took.  So I simply uninstalled the out-of-date version and then re-installed the correct version that I would need.  The references now appear to be working.